# Error during accessing contact using Python Sl4a

Tags: python, python-3.x, sl4a

I'm executing this code to get contacts using `Sl4A` Library:

```
import sl4a
droid=sl4a.Android()
m=droid.contactsGet(['display_name','primary_phone'])
for contact in m:
    print(m[0],"\t",m[1])
    print("\n")
```

The above code is producing

> java.lang.NullPointerException Result(id=1, result =None, error ='Javalang.NullPointerException')